# Relationships between areas for a parallelipiped.

Tags: vectors

Happy New Year!

I came across this conundrum when reviewing 3D vectors.
[image: Question]

I'm really baffled by the solution:
[image: Solution]

The only part I don't understand in the solution is how the equation

Area ABFE = Area ABCD + Area CDEF + Area ADE - Area BCF

gets derived.

There doesn't seem to be a straightforward geometric illustration.
Could anyone offer some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a straight-forward geometric reasoning here. If you have two regions $X, Y$ in the plane then we always have
$$
\operatorname{Area}X=\operatorname{Area}Y +\operatorname{Area}(X\setminus Y) -\operatorname{Area}(Y\setminus X)
$$
In this case, they have described $\operatorname{Area}Y$ as the sum of the two parallelograms, while each of the two set differences are the triangles you see.

Comment: I get it now, thanks! The key idea seems to be that the parallelograms are coplanar, which I omitted. Now it makes perfect sense.